# How to access AnyHashable Data in Swift Firebase remote Notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, appdelegate

I am attempting to access a certain data tag and show an alert if it is not null in the following remote notification:

```
[AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): ************, AnyHashable("google.c.fid"): asdfjkl1234556, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Shipment is no longer available and has been removed from the app.
        title = "Shipment ****** no longer available";
    };
}, 
AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1234567891234567, 
AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1,
 AnyHashable("shipmentMessage"): ****** is no longer available and has been removed form the app.]
```

AnyHashable("shipmentMessage"): ****** is no longer available and has been removed form the app is what I am trying to access. I believe my code should not be calling this null:

```
 if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active{
          print("ACTIVE< CHECK > SHIPMENT MESSAGE : : : : : : \(String(describing: userInfo["shipmentMessage"] as? [AnyHashable:Any]))")
              guard let arrAPS = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
             
              guard let arrAlert = arrAPS["alert"] as? [String:Any] else { return }

                      
          if (userInfo["shipmentMessage"] as? [AnyHashable:Any]) != nil {
         
              print("***********NOT NULL***************")
              let strTitle:String = arrAlert["title"] as? String ?? ""
              let strBody:String = arrAlert["body"] as? String ?? ""
                      let alert = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strBody, preferredStyle: .alert)
                      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { action in
                          print("OK Action")
                      })
                      self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true)
          
          
          } else {
              print("The shipmentMessage was null")
          }
      }
```

Is it the way I am iterating to the shipment message? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: the value of `userInfo["shipmentMessage"]` is a `String`, not a dictionary, so your conditional cast fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace AnyHashable to string like this `(userInfo["shipmentMessage"] as? [String:Any])`

or copy paste this below code -

```
if (userInfo["shipmentMessage"] as? [String:Any]) != nil {
         
              print("***********NOT NULL***************")
              let strTitle:String = arrAlert["title"] as? String ?? ""
              let strBody:String = arrAlert["body"] as? String ?? ""
                      let alert = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strBody, preferredStyle: .alert)
                      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { action in
                          print("OK Action")
                      })
                      self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true)
          
          
          } else {
              print("The shipmentMessage was null")
          }
```